# Create 15minute time intervals from given time in a column and find count of values in each time interval

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given this dataset that contains the **datetime for an event** and the **datetime of ticket scan**

| event_name | event_datetime | scan_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Game 1 | 2018-10-17 19:30:00 | 2018-10-17 20:01:20 2018-10-17 19:20:10 2018-10-17 21:44:43 2018-10-17 20:30:46 2018-10-17 19:51:56 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Game 2 | 2019-04-10 19:30:00 | 2019-04-10 19:39:35 2019-04-10 30:30:49 2019-04-10 20:41:10 2019-04-10 19:46:20 2019-04-10 22:24:19 |

And the desired output should be a column with every 15 minute time intervals before and after *event_datetime* with values of *scan_datetime*

| Time_intervals | 90-75 | 75-60 | 60-45 | 45-30 | 30-15 | 15-0 | 0-15 | 15-30 | 30-45 | 45-60 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| count | 2 | 1 | 5 | 6 | 4 | 3 | 25 | 7 | 4 | 1 |

Comment: So what is your question? Just sort the scan_datetimes for every event and create intervals in order earlier to later and fill this Time_intervals.

Comment: Do you want and aggregation of all games or a separate one for each game?

Comment: Is `scan_datetime` is a list?

Comment: @BorutFlis I want an aggregation for all games. A new table will be created with intervals based on the old one.

Comment: @Corralien Nope. It is actually a row values in the table with *event_name* and *event_datetime* being common for that row.

Comment: @RustamA. The first table contains all the date&time for each scan for every game. I have grouped them according to the event. My task is to create a new table which contains 15min time_intervals before and after all the games. Basically, I want to find which interval before or after the game contains the most scans.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to extract datetime from `scan_datetime` column then explode it.
Next, compute the time delta between `event_datetime` and `scan_datetime` columns. Finally, bin values and count number of occurrences.

```
DT = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
df['scan_datetime'] = df['scan_datetime'].str.findall(DT)

df = df.explode('scan_datetime').astype({'event_datetime': 'datetime64', 
                                         'scan_datetime': 'datetime64'})

df['diff'] = df['event_datetime'].sub(df['scan_datetime']).dt.total_seconds().div(60)

bins = np.arange(24*-15, 24*15+1, 15)
labels = [f'{abs(i)}-{abs(j)}' for i, j in zip(bins, bins[1:])]

out = pd.cut(df['diff'], bins=bins, labels=labels) \
        .value_counts(sort=False).to_frame('count').T
```

Output:

```
>>> out
       180-165  165-150  150-135  135-120  120-105  105-90  90-75  75-60  60-45  45-30  ...  30-45  45-60  60-75  75-90  90-105  105-120  120-135  135-150  150-165  165-180
count        1        0        0        1        0       0      0      3      0      1  ...      0      0      0      0       0        0        0        0        0        0

[1 rows x 24 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

First you explode the list in scan_datetime.

```
df = df.explode("scan_datetime").reset_index(drop=True)
```

This will make each scan a separate row. I am assuming the values in the list are strings, so we convert them to datetime:

```
df["scan_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["scan_datetime"])
```

Than you calculate the difference:

```
df["diff"] = df["event_datetime"] - df["scan_datetime"]
df["diff"] = (df["diff"].dt.total_seconds()/60).astype(int)
```

Now you differences in minutes(signed integers). Than you run value counts with the specified intervals.

```
df["diff"].value_counts(bins=[-90,-75,-60, -45, -30, -15, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60])
```

Comment: Just what I wanted! THANKS

Comment: @sais. You said `scan_datetime` was not a list?

Comment: you should accept one of the answers, they are both correct. @Corralien 's solution is even better as it accounts for the situation where the dates are in string.